# SameSite=Lax works remotely but not in local

Tags: web-services, cookies, http-headers, webserver, samesite

I am seeing some behavior I can't explain when setting a cookie inside an iframe with `SameSite=Lax`.

I have two web servers, one on `your.example.com` and another in `my.example.com`. 
`your.example.com` loads `my.example.com` inside an iframe, where `my.example.com` sets a cookie. This works fine on the actual remote web servers and the cookie gets set without any issue.

On my local environment, I load one in `localhost`, which then loads `my.localhost` inside an iframe. When `my.localhost` returns the cookie, I see the following error in the Chrome Networking Tab:
`The set-cookie had the "SameSite=Lax" attribute but came from a cross-origin response.`

If I load the `my.localhost` address on its own tab the cookie gets set correctly but when I got back `localhost` I see the following error in addition to the previous error message:
`This cookie had the "SameSite=Lax" attribute and the request was made on a different site. This does not include navigation requests initiated by other sites.`

I am using Chrome Version 80.0.3987.162 (Official Build) (64-bit). Can someone please explain this behavior and how to make this work locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will get the behaviour you want if you shift everything down a level. By this I mean, treat `dev.localhost` or a similar subdomain as your top-level domain. Set cookies from the `dev.localhost` domains and you should see `my.dev.locahost` and `your.dev.localhost` treated as same site. In other words, your `SameSite=Lax` cookies should be allowed.

*Caveat:* I need to go back and double check this again, but I'm reasonably sure this worked when I tested a similar set up! So, please try this yourself and verify.

Comment: I will give this a try and get back to you. In the meantime, could you explain why moving it one level down should work?

Comment: That did work. Thanks a lot. I would still love to know why that works.

Comment: @JavierCarmona It's late. But I'm learning about this right now. Apparently `localhost` isn't a "proper" domain, as in it should have at least one dot("."). While `localhost` works alone, `my.localhost` is considered a "top domain", making `my.localhost` and `your.localhost` both "top domain" and are different "site". By appending so it's `dev.localhost`, that becomes a proper top domain, which makes both `my.dev.localhost` and `your.dev.localhost` subdomains of `dev.localhost`, which are same site (not "same origin" though just in case).